# I cant find any of my minecraft forge 1.8.8 files?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I  have a Windows 10 laptop and i have been looking Everywhere for my /.minecraft/bin, 7zip or WinRar, META-INF or my Minecraft.jar and i cant find them anywhere. i tried to go to my downloads but my laptop wont allow me so im thinking i=theu are in there. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The minecraft files are in `%appdata%/.minecraft/versions` since the switch to the new launcher.

Answer (score 1):

Since the new launcher system introduced in 1.6, the `bin` folder was replaced with a `versions` folder containing separate folders for each version of Minecraft you have installed, containing a .jar file and a .json file.

However, you mainly don't even need to modify these anymore since you can instead use the **installer** provided by Forge itself on its official [download page](http://files.minecraftforge.net). Using those instead of installing Forge manually works just as well and much easier.

Answer (score 0):

As texenox said,
Since the new launcher system introduced in 1.6, the bin folder was replaced with a versions folder containing separate folders for each version of Minecraft you have installed, containing a .jar file and a .json file, So you could go to appdata/roaming/.minecraft/mods If you want to see forge mods, And you can go to appdata/roaming/.minecraft./versions If you want to see forge file,The forge file should look like this : "1.8.8-Forge11.14.1.1412" or something.